# jQuery Appending script to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that jQuery automatically parses script elements and append them to the head, however I dont have much of a choice. I need to insert an html string exactly into a specified div. so for example `<script src='http://.....'></script>` into `<div id="lb"></div>`.

The problem is that the scripts get loaded from a server which I have no control over and is using a `document.write()` script. So if that gets appended to the header, there will be severe issues. How can I do this with or without jQuery?

Comment: If the script contains `document.write`, you will have issues, no matter where you insert it. It will replace the whole document.

Comment: @FelixKling It won't replace the whole document... It will insert the script at the end of the document.

Comment: @Willem: Maybe we are  talking about different things. I was under the assumption that the script tag is dynamically generated or loaded, *after* the page was loaded. In that case, `document.write` will erase the  current document. If the page is not fully parsed then `document.write` will just insert the content where it was called. But maybe I read too much into this question.

Comment: Are you talking about loading content/script with AJAX ?

Comment: No, basically the script loaded, renders HTML directly where the script is inserted. this script should not be loaded in the header. But i need to dynamically insert it into a specified div

Comment: We cannot really help you unless we know how you get the script tag. Some code would be helpful. But as said, if you do this *after* the pages was loaded, it will replace the whole content.

Comment: I tried hacking something together (involving a sick collection of timeouts and iframes), but couldn't get it to work without the script you don't control *explicitly* calling `document.open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So to rephrase your question:

You want to insert some `< script >` tags in your page. These tags load javascript files that have `document.write()` in them.

Now you want the `document.write()` to happen in some divs, and not in the header.

I think you would then need to render those script tags directly in the source of your page from the very start. Felix noted correctly that when you load thse script tags later, the whole page will be replaced by what is outputted by the document.write() function.

Thus, javascript or JQuery *cannot* load these script tags. You should render them serverside in the initial version of your page..!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your script to alter the content of you page you could insert it in an iframe instead of a div ? `document` should refer to the iframe then. I don't exactly get what you want though.

Answer (score -1):

Document.write() will put the script at the end of the document (afaik). Then, you would need to look-up these script-tags and put them into the proper DIVs (with a $(elm).append(scriptObj)).

But I might not understand what your problem is...

Comment: If the page was not fully parsed yet, `document.write` will insert the content at the place (or after) it was called. If the page was already parsed, it will replace the whole page. More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write